# Why doesn't the ImageButton work for me? Grid IOS Telerik

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, telerik, maui

I'm creating a project in .Net MAUI for IOS I've tested the operation on Android and it hasn't given me any problems, when I tried it on IOS it has been the opposite. I have an ImagenButton which works and triggers the command while on IOS it doesn't. The error is as follows:

`Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'BindingContext' property not found on 'formaciones.ViewModels.Formacion.ActoViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ImageButton.Command'`

And on the screen I get the button but even if I tap it doesn't do anything.

Here's the button in the view:

```
<telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" IsVisible="True">
    <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vmodels:ActoViewModel">
            <ImageButton x:Name="elimina" Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectionCommand, Source={x:Reference ActosL}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding IdActo}"
                WidthRequest="26" HeightRequest="26"
                IsEnabled="True">
                <ImageButton.Source>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="Iconsj" Glyph="" Color="LightCoral"/>
                </ImageButton.Source>
            </ImageButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
</telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In the view code:

```cs
public ActoView() {      
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new ActoViewModel(this, new LocalDbService());
    BindingContext = vm; 
}
```

and in the viewModel:

```
public ICommand SelectionCommand { get; }
public ActoViewModel()
{

}

public ActoViewModel(Page currentPage, LocalDbService dbService)
{
    database = dbService;
    _currentPage = currentPage;

    LoadData();
    CargaTitulo();
    
    SelectionCommand = new Command(async (idActo) => await GuardarIdAc(idActo));

}

public async Task GuardarIdAc(object idActo)
{
    IdActo = int.Parse(idActo.ToString());
}
```

I've tried to move the button but even if I put it inside another grid it doesn't work

The error is from my grid, in Adroid I can tap the button but in IOS can't

```
<Grid>
<Grid RowDefinitions="*">
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" Margin="10">
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <telerik:RadDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <telerik:RadDataGrid.Columns>
                <telerik:DataGridDateColumn PropertyName="FechaInicio" HeaderText="Fecha" CanUserFilter="False"/>
                <telerik:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Acto" HeaderText="Formacion" CanUserFilter="False"/>
                <telerik:DataGridNumericalColumn PropertyName="IdActo" HeaderText="id" IsVisible="False" CanUserFilter="False"/>
                <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" IsVisible="True">
                    <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageButton x:Name="modificar"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectionCommand3, Source={x:Reference Actos}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding IdActo}"
                                WidthRequest="26"
                                HeightRequest="26"
                                IsEnabled="True">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="Iconsj" Glyph="&#xE802;" Color="Grey"/>
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" IsVisible="True">
                    <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageButton x:Name="elimina"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectionCommand2, Source={x:Reference Actos}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding IdActo}"
                                WidthRequest="26"
                                HeightRequest="26"
                                IsEnabled="True">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="Iconsj" Glyph="&#xE801;" Color="LightCoral"/>
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderText="">
                    <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageButton x:Name="SelectedButton"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectionCommand, Source={x:Reference Actos}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding IdActo}"
                                WidthRequest="26"
                                HeightRequest="26"
                                IsEnabled="True">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="Iconsj" Glyph="&#xF064;" Color="Green"/>
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </telerik:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        </telerik:RadDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

if I put the button for example in a <Shell.TitleView> it works for me.

Comment: does `ActoViewModel` have a `BindingContext` property?

Comment: I've initialized  it in the View.cs I need anything else? is that on Android I can do the command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you got confused in your binding : it should be `Command="{Binding SelectionCommand [...]}`, instead of `{Binding BindingContext.SelectionCommand}`.

Comment: Basically Binding is looking *into* your BindingContext. here your Button trying to call a mtehod named `BindingContext.BindingContext.SelectionCommand`, and can't find it for obvious reasons. The BindingContext is implicit when you do some bindings.

Comment: when I do that it still doesn't work on IOS and it stops working on Andorid

Comment: Also, in your viewmodel (or at least in the code you shared), your command is named `SelectionCommandId` instead of `SelectionCommand`. Update the names and tell us if it works :)

Comment: for example the command is this : public ICommand SelectionCommand =>
     new Command(GuardarIdAc);
 public async void GuardarIdAc(object idActo)
 {
     IdActo = int.Parse(idActo.ToString());
 }

Comment: Any of the commands do anything

Comment: I can't really test it, as I don't have Telerik, try it with a regular Command with just `Console,WriteLine("Hello World!")`and no command parameter.

Comment: I've put breaking points but it doesn't go in through any, in IOS, It's like I don't detect them

Comment: Is a error from my grid